# Password Expiration Date

Tags: vb.net

I want to check the Active Directory "Password Expiration Date" in vb.net.

I found this :

```
 DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path)
 ActiveDs.IADsUser native = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)entry.NativeObject;
 DateTime passwordExpirationDate = native.PasswordExpirationDate;
```

But it is not for vb.net. If someone can help me ?

Thank You !

Comment: Although someone was kind enough to help you with an answer, you should know that these types of questions (code conversion) are off topic on this site.  I would recommend you read the [help] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

VB.net equivalent:

```
Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(path)

Dim native As ActiveDs.IADsUser = DirectCast(entry.NativeObject, ActiveDs.IADsUser)

Dim passwordExpirationDate As DateTime = native.PasswordExpirationDate
```

Comment: Thank you very much to answer me ! But i have some errors like i can't debug. Can you explain me what is "path" on the code please ?

Comment: @H.A.W.X : How should we know? It was you who found that snippet (the `path` is in your question too). My guess, it is where you should put the path to the AD.